# Working hours between two dates in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to calculate working hours between two dates in snowflake without creating tables?
i have tried function like (datediff) and timestamp but i could not reach the solution

i would like to get something like that

```
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
|       create_Task   |        Solved_Task  | BusinessHours |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
| 2012-03-05 09:00:00 | 2012-03-05 15:00:00 |  6.000000     |
| 2012-03-05 10:00:00 | 2012-03-06 10:00:00 |  8.000000     |
| 2012-03-05 11:00:00 | 2012-03-06 10:00:00 |  7.000000     |
| 2012-03-05 10:00:00 | 2012-03-06 15:00:00 | 13.000000     |
| 2012-03-09 16:00:00 | 2012-03-12 10:00:00 |  2.000000     |
| 2012-03-06 16:00:00 | 2012-03-15 10:00:00 | 50.000000     |
| 2012-03-09 16:00:00 | 2012-03-19 10:00:00 | 42.000000     |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
```

and i would like to specify the working hours so then i can calculate the business hours

Comment: You would need to write your own function to achieve this, incorporating your specific requirements as to what constitutes "business hours", how to handle partial hours, etc.

Comment: Please share sample input and desired results

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is by creating a working hours table. Then you can run a fairly simple query:

```
select
  t.id
  , sum(datediff(‘second’, 
               -- calculate the max of the two start time
               (case when t.start <= 
                          w.working_day_start_timestamp
                     then w.working_day_start_timestamp
                     else t.start
                end),
               -- calculate the min of the two end times
               (case when t.end >= 
                          w.working_day_end_timestamp
                     then w.working_day_end_timestamp
                     else t.end 
                end)
               )) / 3600 -- convert to hourly
  as working_hour_diff
from 
  working_days_times w,
  cross join time_intervals t
where -- select all intersecting intervals
  (
   t.start <= w.working_day_end_timestamp
   and
   t.end >= w.working_day_start_timestamp
  )
and -- select only working days
  w.is_working_day
group by
  t.id
```

If you need a function, this article describes the implementation of a Javascript UDF in Snowflake:
https://medium.com/dandy-engineering-blog/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-working-hours-between-two-timestamps-in-sql-b5696de66e51